# Prevent Automatic Horizontal Scroll On Selected TreeView Item

Tags: c#, wpf

When a TreeViewItem is selected, the horizontal and vertical scrollbars adjust so it's in view.  I like the vertical scrollbar behavior, but I want to stop the horizontal one.  Disabling the horizontal scrollbar has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisability and setting it to Disabled.

```
<TreeView Width="100" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <TreeViewItem Header="This is a very long header with a small width..................123"/>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/bab3fb62-bf9e-4db6-854c-829bd2896319) may guide you ...

Key is to handle BringIntoView event at tree view item level before scrollviewer receives it.